# How can I find the triple integral in this domain?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given,
$$f(x,y,z)=x$$
and
$$
\text{Domain of integration }=V=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: 1+x+y \geq z \geq \sqrt{2x^2 +3y^2}\right\},
$$
how I can find the integral
$$
\iiint\limits_V\!\! f(x,y,z)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z=\iiint\limits_V\!\! x\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \:?
$$
I found similar a questions on the textbook. The boundaries of $z$ are clearly given. In order to find the boundaries of $x$ and $y$ the book set the two sides of the inequality equal and later shows that they form a circle equation. The solution after that was trivial with the help of polar coordinates. But in my case once I set the two sides equal I get an equation with the form 
$$
a(x-b)^2 + c(y-d)^2 +exy = f
$$ 
which represents an off-center rotated ellipse, and I can't find a way to use polar coordinates here. More specifically the equation I got is 
$$
(x-1)^2 + 2(y-1/2)^2 -2xy = 5/2.
$$ 
How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is that part of a cone with elliptical cross sections above $z = 0$ cut by the plane.  We have to examine the domain at each value of $z$.  At each fix $z$, the plane becomes a line $x = z - y - 1$ and the cone becomes an ellipse $2x^2 + 3y^2 = z^2$.  For example at $z = 0$, the line does not touch the cone's apex.  At two values of $z$, the line is tangent to the ellipse.  In between values the line cuts the ellipse at two points.  To find the tangent points:

$$x = z - y - 1$$
$$z^2 = 2x^2 + 3y^2$$

Solve these equation for $y$ in terms of $z$

$$y = \frac{2z - 2 \pm\sqrt{-z^2 + 12z - 6}}{5}$$

These are the y coordinates of the two points cut by the line which will be used for $y$ in the triple integral.

For the tangent set the square root to zero:

$$-z^2 + 12z - 6 = 0 \implies z = 6 \pm \sqrt{30}$$

Please note that for $z$ from $0$ to $6 - \sqrt{30}$ the region is the complete ellipse which is symmetric about the y axis.  As the integrand is an odd function the triple Ingram will be zero.

This is also true when the line cuts the ellipse at two points.  To the left side of the left point and to the right side of the right point the limits are the upper and lower part of the ellipse.  In between the point the limits are the ellipse and the line.

$$I = \int_{6 - \sqrt{30}}^{6 + \sqrt{30}}\int_{\frac{2z - 2 - \sqrt{-z^2 + 12z - 6}}{5}}^{\frac{2z - 2 + \sqrt{-z^2 + 12z - 6}}{5}}\int_{z - y - 1}^{\sqrt{\frac{z^2 - 3y^2}{2}}} xdxdydz$$

$$= \int_{6 - \sqrt{30}}^{6 + \sqrt{30}} \frac{(30 - (z - 6)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{75}$$

Let $z - 6 = \sqrt{30}sin t$

$$I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 30\sqrt{30} cos^3tdt = 40\sqrt{30}$$